# Variables are not showing up when i pass them with sendKeys() in casperjs

Tags: casperjs

I am having an issue with trying to get variables to work. If i substitute a number for the i in my code it works just fine but just having the variable there causes it not to perform the sendKeys task. I've also tried it with fill and it does the same thing. Here is my code any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
for (var i = 0; i < custArr.length; i++) {
    casper.then(function() {
        this.sendKeys('#searchdata2', custArr[i][3]);
        this.sendKeys('#searchdata1', custArr[i][11]);
    });

    casper.thenClick(x('//*[@id="customerSearchForm"]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[6]/input'), function() {
        this.wait(delay, function() {
        });
        casper.capture('test1.png');
        });}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < custArr.length; i++) {
    //IIFE, to avoid it executes custArr.length fois i=custArr.length, we have to create a local scope for each i value
    (function(index){

    casper.then(function() {
        this.sendKeys('#searchdata2', custArr[i][3]);
        this.sendKeys('#searchdata1', custArr[i][11]);
    });

    casper.thenClick(x('//*[@id="customerSearchForm"]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[6]/input'), function() {
        this.wait(delay, function() {
        });
        casper.capture('test1.png');
        });

    })(i);

    }
```

Comment: You should clarify what the thought problem is: Every function call has the same reference to `i` so that `i=custArr.length`, which is obviously out of bounds.

Comment: When i run that it gets me 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'custArr[i][3]'). What I'm doing with this program is i have a custArr[][] that is filled with customer information and Im trying to run a for loop to run through and add every customer in my array to our database website. i will never be equal to custArr.length because it will go until custArr.length - 1 correct? Sorry I am very new to this.